redis in-memory cache (connection issue)
I am trying to connect to a redis in-memory store using the following code. (using redis.from_url). It has an endpoint and is also AUTH and TLS enabled.
Version: redis version 7.
Platform: python3.11 / redis in-memory instance in GCP
import redis
import certifi

REDIS_HOST = <primary endpoint>
REDIS_PORT = 6378
REDIS_PASSWORD = <password>


REDIS_URL = f'rediss://{REDIS_PASSWORD}@{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}?decode_responses=True&protocol=3'
url_connection = redis.from_url(REDIS_URL)
url_connection.ping()

Getting this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 357, in connect
sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 62, in call_with_retry
return do()
^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 358, in
lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1021, in _connect
return self._wrap_socket_with_ssl(sock)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1066, in _wrap_socket_with_ssl
sslsock = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1382, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/EN_ie/redisc_withurl.py", line 43, in
url_connection.ping()
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1212, in ping
return self.execute_command("PING", **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 559, in execute_command
return self._execute_command(*args, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 565, in _execute_command
conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1422, in get_connection
connection.connect()
File "/home/EN_ie/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 363, in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 1 connecting to 10.0.0.5:6378. [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006).


Your client should have the path to the key_file, ca_file and cert_file. You can send pong with tls enable without valid tls connection, in your implementation you use auth, but not tls.
